# small calculation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem with a javascript calculation. I have a function like this:

```
$( "#main-nav li[class]" ).each(function( index ) {
     var position = $(this).offset();
     var width = $(this).width();
     var center = parseInt(position) - (parseInt(width) / 2);
     console.log("Position: " + position.left + ", width: " + width +  ", center: " + center);
});
```

But it results in this. Anyone have an idea how the calculation isn't done?

```
Position: 722, width: 83, center: NaN
```

Answer (score 7):

Give `position.left`

```
$( "#main-nav li[class]" ).each(function( index ) {
     var position = $(this).offset();
     var width = $(this).width();
     var center = parseInt(position.left) - (parseInt(width) / 2);
     console.log("Position: " + position.left + ", width: " + width +  ", center: " + center);
});
```

Comment: always the smallest mistakes, thanks!

Comment: Mistakes happen. No issues! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make the simple correction on this line. Then you will get the desired output..

```
var center = parseInt(position.left) - (parseInt(width) / 2);
```

Comment: @Velter just a simple mistake nothing else..:-)